# mongodb certification mock questions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am preparing for mongodb certifications and in one of the mock tests on tutorialspoint.com i came about a question which goes something like this

Q 3 - Which of the following is correct about MongoDB?

- A - MongoDB uses JSON format to represent documents
- B - MongoDB supports collection joins
- C - MongoDB supports some of the SQLfunctions
- D - MongoDB supports geospatial indexes

Now, i think A,C and D are the correct answers reasons being

- A: Mongodb uses JSON formats to represents documents and internally converts the JSON to BSON formats for storing documents so A is valid.
- C: Some of the SQL functions like GroupBY Max and Min are supported by Mongodb as well.
- D and ofcourse D since Mongodb supports geospatial indexes.

However the answer on tutorialpoints does not match my answers. They say that the correct answer is D

Can anyone put some light what is the correct answer to this question ?

Answer (score 2):

- MongoDB uses BSON format which is binary as opposed to JSON, moreover it supports more data types. [See BSON documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) and [specification](http://bsonspec.org/)
- Some of query operators resemble SQL functions, however it does not supports SQL at all, thus it does not support any of SQL functions. [See documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-support-sql)

Answer (score 0):

- MongoDB 3.2 supports left outer join between collections - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

I think that the correct answer: B and D

Answer (score 0):

**Answer D is correct**, because this question is old and that time there was no join in the mongoDB so it nullify the option B,

And as you said

> Mongodb uses JSON formats to represents documents

No MongoDB saves and fetch BSON documents only, mongoDB language drivers(pymongo, nodejs mongo) convert BSON to JSON and vice versa, there is no conversion in database, all conversion happens in language drivers, so option A is also wrong.

And as @Andriy Simonov said in above answer.

> Some of query operators resemble SQL functions, however it does not
>   supports SQL at all, thus it does not support any of SQL functions.

So answer D is correct in this scenario